# Factor analysis in python (similar to factal() from R)

Tags: python, data-science

I have been struggling to perform factor analysis using sklearn from python.

In R after running the following code:

```
x.f <- factanal(data_final, factors = 2, rotation="varimax",  scores="regression", lower = 0.01)
```

I get the following result :

```
Call:
factanal(x = data_final, factors = 2, scores = "regression", rotation = "varimax", lower = 0.01)

Uniquenesses:
 WTI     GOLD    CAC40      DAX EUR_DOLL YEN_DOLL    SP500   NIKKEI   GILT TEN_TRES 
0.740    0.971    0.115    0.056    0.789    0.775    0.283    0.022    0.849    0.754 

Loadings:
     Factor1 Factor2
WTI       0.400   0.317 
GOLD      0.169         
CAC40     0.857   0.387 
DAX       0.903   0.359 
EUR_DOLL  0.371   0.271 
YEN_DOLL         -0.472 
SP500     0.511   0.675 
NIKKEI    0.337   0.930 
GILT     -0.334  -0.197 
TEN_TRES -0.343  -0.358 

           Factor1 Factor2
SS loadings      2.482   2.163
Proportion Var   0.248   0.216
Cumulative Var   0.248   0.465

Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.
The chi square statistic is 686.84 on 26 degrees of freedom.
The p-value is 4.16e-128
```

I can easily interpret this code, and understand the output and process behind it.

However, when I run the following code in python, I am not sure what is happening and if it is correct.

```
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn.decomposition import FactorAnalysis

factor = decomposition.FactorAnalysis(n_components=2)
factor.fit(data_final.iloc[:, 1::])
factor.components_

array([[-0.01175024, -0.00157749, -0.01547956, -0.01353783, -0.00322834,
     0.00225613, -0.01085127, -0.01219159,  0.00247041,  0.00210084],
   [ 0.00021618, -0.00135881, -0.00419973, -0.00435391, -0.00012713,
    -0.00225637,  0.00275685,  0.00686218,  0.00034337, -0.00035002]])
```

Is there an easier way to perform factor analysis in python? If not, how can I obtain the factor components from my python code?

If its of any use, the dataset I am using is a set of log returns in futures contracts of 10 assets.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the module factor-analyzer (https://pypi.org/project/factor-analyzer/) to do factor analysis in python. It has pretty decent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python package available that wraps the R factanal function so that you can just call it from python with a pandas data frame like this:

```
from factanal.wrapper import factanal

fa_res = factanal(pdf, factors=4, scores='regression', rotation='promax', 
                  verbose=True, return_dict=True)
```

More information:
https://pypi.org/project/factanal/

Install with:

```
pip install factanal
```

Answer (score -1):

So I found the reason why I didn’t get the same output. Sklearn function does not standarize your data while R facanal() does. I had to scale my data in order to get similar outputs. Another question would be why this makes such a big difference when I am working with log returns and not prices.